# Using cin in for loop defiition

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple program with `std::cin` in the for loop body.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float a = 0;
    for (std::cin >> a; a >= 0;std::cin >> a) {
        std::cout << "\t "<<a<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program takes value in `a` and prints it until you enter a negative number.
But when I modify `for` loop definition as `for(std::cin >> a; a >= 0;)` it just prints first number forever. I am wondering why this is happening. Is it because loop increment part missing?

Comment: because you removed the part that pauses program and waits for the user to enter a new number.

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/loop.html See "Translating for-loops"

Comment: Why not just use a while loop instead? Then you can get user input at the end of the loop and check to see if they have entered a sentinel value - if not, it will run again.

Comment: Certainly. But my question is why `for(std::cin >> a; a >= 0;)` doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I think there is nothing to wonder about; omitting the "third" part of the for-loop means that there is - apart from the loop's body - nothing that will be executed after each iteration; hence, once the loop is entered by having provided a value for `a >= 0`, and as long as you do not alter the value of `a` in the loop's body (and `std::cout << "\t "<<a<<"\n"` will not alter `a`), the loop will run "for ever", always printing `a`'s initial value.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is not proper for these situations. Use `while` instead of `for`.

A for loop is generally used when you know how many iterations of the loop you want to execute - or it is calculable. A while loop, or do...while loop is more appropriate here than a for loop because you do not know how many times the user wants to execute the loop.

Here are some references that can give you more information on the differences between the types of loop structures in C++.

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/do-while-loop
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float a = 0;
    while(a>=0){
        std::cout << "value: ";
        std::cin >> a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Better way is below.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float a;
    do{
        std::cout << "value: ";
        std::cin >> a;
    }
    while(a>=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "for is not proper for these situations" -- why not ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my question is *why* `for(std::cin >> a; a >= 0;)` doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulR Updated.

Answer (score 1):

In this for loop

```
for(std::cin >> a; a >= 0;)
```

the first expression of the statement `std::cin >> a` is evaluated only once before the first iteration of the loop. So the variable `a` will not be changed any more within the loop and the loop will be infinite.

Take into account that this loop

```
for (std::cin >> a; a >= 0;std::cin >> a) {
    std::cout << "\t "<<a<<"\n";
}
```

is also wrong because the user can interrupt the input. In this case the variable `a` will not be changed and you will again get an infinite loop.

Instead of these statements

```
float a = 0;
for (std::cin >> a; a >= 0;std::cin >> a) {
    std::cout << "\t "<<a<<"\n";
}
```

it will be better to write

```
for ( float a; std::cin >> a && a >= 0; ) {
    std::cout << "\t "<<a<<"\n";
}
```

There is no need to declare the variable `a` outside the loop because it is used only within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

When a loop is called first is this code execute

```
int i = 0
```

after that it checks the test

```
i >= 0
```

and for every iteration it checks the test and then to the incresment part

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 0;std::cin >> a) {
   //code
}
```

and since you left empty the incresment part, the *a* is printed forever!